# Cocos 2d error in call import module

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have imported my Cocos2d project code in eclipse with library libcocos2dx but it is showing error in the Android.mk file .

I am attaching that file code .Error occurring in the last line of code.

//Android.mk file code

```
$(call import-module,.)//Error in this line
```

I am using libcocos2dx library but not getting any result.I have also cross verified SDK path and NDk path.
Please let me know any use full solution for this.I have tried alot but fail every time .Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what might the error that "it" shows be, exactly?

Comment: Getting this error make: *** Android NDK: Aborting. . Stop.
on this line $(call import-module,.)